# Combining Wait Handles?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mono, waithandle

Bit of an interesting one here I think. I have a class thats in charge of "multiplexing" a number of processing operations onto a fixed number of threads. The typical case is a sort of producer/consumer problem, where each operation consists of a WaitHandle (in this case, the semaphore that tracks how many items are in the queue) and a delegate to invoke.

For example, If I have two producers (A and B), producing items into two seperate queues. Rather than create two consumer threads for each producer (A1,A2,B1,B2), I'm multiplexing the four consumers "threads" onto two threads. The code for this "multiplexer" runs something like this (simplified a bit):

```
WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[2];
waitHandles[0] = NumberOfItemsFullInProducerAQueue;
waitHandles[1] = NumberOfItemsFullInProducerBQueue;
while(true)
{
    int index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);
    if(index == 0)
    {
        // handle the item from queue A
    }
    else
    {
        // handle the item from queue B
    }
}
```

I'm trying to extend this concept onto a slightly more complicated example, where an action might need multiple wait handles to be satisfied before it is executed. I'm wondering if there is some sort of WaitHandle.Combine(waitHandle1, waitHandle2) call I can make to combine two wait handles together into a single wait handle. The end result would be something like:

```
A,B,C,D are waitHandles
E = Combine(A, B)
F = Combine(C, D)
waitHandles = { E, F }

while(true)
{
   int index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);
   if(index == 0)
   {
   }
   else
   {
   }
}
```

**Extra Points?**

Although not a requirement, it might also be really nice if the combinations of wait handles could intersect. For example, something like this:

```
  A,B,C are waitHandles
  D = Combine(A, B)
  E = Combine(A, C)
  waitHandles = { D, E }
  // same as above from here
```

Thanks for your help SO

Comment: Extra points?  I'll wait for the bounty then.

Comment: Did I do some sort of an SO community no-no with that? ( Further evidence of the internet's need for sarcasm-script to make situations like this unambiguous )...

Comment: @LorenVS I think what Hans is trying to point out is that you can actually award those extra points via a bounty rather them being metaphysical. Otherwise what does and for "extra points" actually mean? Do we get to play with the hamster?

Comment: Everybody loves hamsters, but I see what you mean

Comment: This is not possible natively because the kernel doesn't support it. You could try to emulate it by manually checking signal states, though (won't work with objects that need side-effects when a wait is satisfied).

Comment: @wj32 Thanks for the info. I think I may end up implementing a way to keep track of which wait handles have been succesfully waited on, and use that information to decide which action's can be invoked.

Comment: @wj32: You can do it, sort of, by having another thread waiting on a subset and setting an event when the condition is met.  I say "sort of" because it's no longer atomic, which is a problem in some scenarios but still useful in others.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider looking into the new [Barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier.aspx) class in the .NET 4 TPL (back-ported to 3.5 as part of [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx).  It's specifically designed for the scenarios you describe, where you need to block execution until multiple cooperating tasks have reached a checkpoint.  You can also use the Task system to create sophisticated continuation paths, with one Task depending on two prior completing, dependent on a first Task completing and, if Exceptions occur at any point, having those Exceptions aggregated and reported in a central location.

Comment: Hmm... I figured Tasks would be the solution, I may have to start doing some transitions to use them more...

Comment: The example in the linked MSDN page of the Barrier class uses the most colorful language I've ever seen on MSDN. The use of phrases such as "D'oh!", "Nope -- changed my mind" and "hunky-dory" make me think it was written by a developer rather than a technical writer, which adds a human touch to it (although it might appeal less to a wider international audience where such phrases might be detrimental to readability).

Comment: @LorenVS, I've enjoyed working with Tasks on recent projects.  There's a lot of depth to the TPL, especially once you start looking into dependent Task continuation (Task C requires that A and B complete successfully first, possibly in parallel), cooperative cancellation, and the way it manages exception handling for you.  I've coded many, many pieces of Threading plumbing code in different ways for different projects over the years, so it's nice to finally see this functionality packaged up in the BCL.